# I want to run a script to compare two workbooks and validate data from workbook 1 to workbook 2

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am working with a "master" excel (Workbook 1) that has two columns in it. Column A lists "Order Types" and Column B lists "Requirement". My second excel (Workbook 2) will also have "Order Types" in column A. Column B, however, will be blank. I want to be able to run a script that validates the data from Columns  A & B on Workbook 1 and inserts it into Column B on Workbook 2.

[Workbook 1 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxTTD.png)

[Workbook 2 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJzdm.png)

A simple VLOOKUP formula does it fine, (below for example), but want to add a macro that I can run. I am having trouble finding VBA script tutorials online that meet my needs.

=VLOOKUP(A5,'[Data Test.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B, 2, FALSE)

Comment: Does "automated" mean you want something that adds the formula? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think automated was the right word. I just want the script right now. I edited my question above, thanks! @braX

Comment: So you are asking someone to write code for you that loops and performs the same thing as the VLOOKUP?

Comment: Yes, if that is possible. Sorry, I am not the best with the more advanced features of excel.

Answer (score 0):

### A Classic VBA Lookup Using Late-Bound Excel Functions

```vb
Sub ClassicLookup()
    ' Source
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks("Data Test.xlsx")
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim slrg As Range: ' Lookup
    Set slrg = sws.Range("A2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns("B") ' Return
    ' Destination
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' ???
    Dim dlrg As Range: ' Lookup
    Set dlrg = dws.Range("A2", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Dim drrg As Range: Set drrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns("B") ' Return
    ' Lookup.
    With Application
        drrg.Value = .IfError(.Index(srrg, .Match(dlrg, slrg, 0)), "")
    End With
End Sub
```